# Does pronunciation of "livelihood" differ by county?

Tags: pronunciation

I met a person who pronounced "**livelihood**" like "**lifelihood**".

Is there a some kind of dialect like this?

Maybe I just misheard her pronunciation.

Comment: Where is the person from? Is she a native speaker?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is not providing any details based on which we need to answer the question.

Comment: @Rathony She was Australian. It seems like that was just my misheard. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never encountered the word 'lifelihood' (pronunciation). Likely misheard (or the speaker pronounced 'wrongly') because /v/ and /f/ are both [labiodental consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labiodental_consonant).

**Labiodental consonants** are articulated with the lower lip and the upper teeth.

Comment: Since /f/ is a voiceless labiodental fricative it seems somewhat plausible that there might be an accent where a non-initial voiced labiodental fricative becomes voiceless. The other possibility might be a non native speaker of a language where "v" is pronounced /f/ such as German. I believe that in the 'allo 'allo series at least some of the German accents had the property of turning voiced labiodental fricatives to voiceless ones even in word initial situations.

Comment: @DRF, Yes, this is possible, and was possibly read and pronounced in German. (Awaiting ironsand's answer to Rathony's questions)

Comment: @DRF +1) I suspected it (German, Austrian, maybe Russian?), too. But who knows. It is difficult to answer this question without knowing the person's nationality unless we have members from all the countries in the world. I voted to close it.

Comment: My native British dialect pronunciation results in these two sounds being so similar as almost being indistinct to a non-native ear. We usually switch to standard English when speaking to a non-native speaker to avoid precisely this problem.